# access mongo db on digital ocean server from another machine

Tags: python, mongodb, remote-access, digital-ocean

I have a ubuntu 14.04 droplet set up on a digital ocean server. I have installed mongodb in that server. I have created a database which i can access using

```
pymongo.Mongoclient()
```

from a python shell in the server. But I want to create a remote connection to the database from my local machine ( or any other machine). How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [mongo connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) and then [pass that to MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient).

For example:

```
mongo_url = 'mongodb://db1.example.net:2500/'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client.db_name
collection = db.collection_name
```

Comment: but how to get the necessary info for the connection string? I know the host ip. but i have no clue how to find the port on which the db is running. Is there any settings file created while creating the db which has this info?

Comment: @NilabjaRay Why don't you know that? Is it not your mongo running? Can you ask the person who set it up? Why not try the mongo default port first? Can you log into the box and try `ps aux | grep mongo`?

Comment: I don't know because i don't know where to look. I created the database from python using pymongo.Mongoclient() function. I didn't give it any argument. By default it creates a database in the local server at port 27017. I tried using my digital ocean droplet ip and this port as the uri. it didnt work.

Comment: this is what i got when i ran the command you mentioned. What does this tell? I have no clue  
 
`mongodb   6598  0.6 14.5 2829804 147780 ?      Ssl  Aug05 281:50 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
    neel     14083  0.0  0.0  11740   940 pts/0    S+   12:06   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo`